# Conflicts while installing Samba 4.3 on CentOS 6.7

Tags: centos, samba

I tried to upgrade samba from version 4.0.0rc4 to 4.3.x on a CentOS 6.7 x64 system. I found the following repo that contains the needed packages:

http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/network:samba:STABLE/CentOS_6/network:samba:STABLE.repo

Listed at:

https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=network%3Asamba%3ASTABLE&package=samba

However, I'm running into conflicts when I add the repo to `/etc/yum.repos.d`. Running a `yum update` ends with:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib64/libtalloc.so.2 from install of libtalloc2-2.1.5-84.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libtalloc-2.0.7-2.el6.x86_64
```

Trying to install samba 4.3 brings up two additional conflicts:

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib64/libtalloc.so.2 from install of libtalloc2-2.1.5-84.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libtalloc-2.0.7-2.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libtevent.so.0 from install of libtevent0-0.9.26-79.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libtevent-0.9.18-3.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libtdb.so.1 from install of libtdb1-1.3.8-95.1.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libtdb-1.2.10-1.el6.x86_64
```

Is anybody using that repo above and got this working? Or did perhaps someone install samba 4.3 and can point me to a solution?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**edit:** I added the actual repository URL which is labeled CentOS 6 so I assumed this is an CentOS repository **hosted** at openSuSE - which it kind of is. However it contains packages of openSuSE's open build service and the particular ones above are not stable. Leaving this here in case someone else faces similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use an OpenSuse repository on a CentOS machine and expect it to work. This is the wrong way to install packages.

Doing a quick search, I can not find samba packages newer then 4.0.x for CentOS6. You have two possibilities:

1. try to use CentOS7 packages, with Samba 4.2.x
2. download Samba source code and compile it

Please note that both approach are far from ideal (but better than using a package for another distro!).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I expected it to be a CentOS repository since they provide different URLs for SLES, CentOS and so on. What's the purpose of that?

Answer (score 0):

That repo is probably built with CentOS6 in mind, but .. well, let's say there are several layers of reasons why this could be a bad idea.  You have your Grain of Salt?  Okay.

You're installing samba over samba, which is fine, but its dependency is misnamed in an attempt to avoid the very thing you're encountering;  the packager isn't experienced.  So you will want to work around the dependency issue, keeping in mind that replacing libtalloc with libtalloc2 will probably cause a few other apps to break when they're looking for libtalloc and its payload and they don't find it installed.

1. Try ripping out all of samba and all its dependencies.  Really, the easiest way to do this is to try installing that hacked samba package and its deps, and then removing any conflicts.  Lather, rinse, repeat.
2. Install the yum replace plugin from IUS.  They're a better repo, but we're only here for the plugin.  Install that, and then try 
   `yum replace samba --replace-with samba`

   and let's see whether it'll figure out that there are indirect dependency issues for it to solve.  It'll complain about SOME missing deps, as it always does, but it'll present you with a firing solution before you pull the trigger.  Take a look at it and see if it makes sense before committing.

   Or have another VM you can spark up because this is just a test box, and nothing important is on it, right?

I think you're looking at the same repo that's in my to-do list; but I was planning on taking it and hooking up github to the other builder service whose name eludes me, and update the package semi-automatically so that the maintenance won't be a hassle.  Seeing as the regular alt package source went mercenary, we're all rather scrambling for another samba with proper AD+kerb support again (but if it's too hard for RedHat to get after a decade, why try, right?)